# coordinate number format \ang{}

Tags: formatting, siunitx, angle

In a table, I am listing several coordinates. I want to use a number format such as this

> W 95°13'14''
>
> W 95°03'00''
>
> ...

I am using the `\ang{}` environment of the `siunitx` package.

However, there seems to be no control over the number format when e.g. W 94°02'09'', then `W\ang{94;02;09}` produces **W94°2'9''** i.e. eliminates automatically the zeros in the decade positions.

Is there a way to define a number format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the right option, either locally:

```
W\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{94;2;9}
```

or globally:

```
\sisetup{minimum-integer-digits=2}
 W\ang{94;2;9}
```

[image]

Comment: Or doing `\newcommand{\latitude}[2]{#1\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{#2}}`, then typing `\latitude{W}{94;2;9}`

Comment: (just btw: West and East prefixes refer to the longitude and N and S to latitude)